images not rendering on Gatsby using GatsbyImage
I'm having trouble getting images to load on my website using GatsbyImage and would love any help with this resolving this.
This is what I have on the page where I'm expecting the images to render:
**10-tea-recipes.js
**
        <div className="space-y-8">
          {teaRecipes.map((recipe) => {
            const imageNode = allFile.find(file => file.name === recipe.image); // Match by name
            const recipeImage = imageNode ? getImage(imageNode.childImageSharp) : null; // Get image data
            return (
              <div key={recipe.id} className="border-b pb-8">
                {recipeImage && (
                  <GatsbyImage image={recipeImage} alt={recipe.title} className="w-full h-64 object-cover mb-4" />
                )}
                <h3 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-2">{recipe.id.toString().padStart(2, '0')}  {recipe.title}</h3>
                <p className="mb-4">{recipe.description}</p>
                <SecondaryButton to={`/tea-recipe/${recipe.id}`}>
                  GET THE RECIPE
                </SecondaryButton>
              </div>

When I checked the console, I'm seeing that ImageNode is undefined and recipeImage is null.
Here is the GraphQL query:
**10-tea-recipes.js
**
export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allTeaRecipe {
      nodes {
        id
        title
        description
        image
      }
    }
    allFile {
      nodes {
        name
        publicURL
        childImageSharp {
          gatsbyImageData
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

Here's an example of the recipe data I'm pulling from
teaRecipe.mjs
export const teaRecipes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Spring: Lavender Earl Grey Latte",
    description: "A perfect way to welcome the warmer weather with floral notes of lavender combined with the robust flavor of Earl Grey.",
    image: "lavendar_latte.webp", 
    ingredients: [
      "1 cup of hot water",
      "1 Earl Grey tea bag",
      "1 tsp dried lavender",
      "1/2 cup steamed milk (or a dairy-free alternative)",
      "1-2 tsp honey or your preferred sweetener"
    ],
    instructions: [
      "Brew the Earl Grey tea in hot water, adding the dried lavender.",
      "Let it steep for 5-7 minutes, then strain.",
      "Pour the tea into a mug, add honey, and top with steamed milk.",
      "Garnish with a sprinkle of lavender buds if desired."
    ]
  },

**gatsby-config.js
**
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`,
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-postcss',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'data',
        path: `${__dirname}/src/data/`,
      },
    },
  ],
}

Any feedback hear would be greatly appreciated. I'm very new to this, thank you!
I tried logging the error points on the console and here's what I'm seeing for one of the items:
All Files: (8) ['basil_iced_tea', 'chai_cider', 'hot_chocolate', 'pumpkin_latte', 'macha_lemonade', 'habiscus_tea', 'lavendar_latte', 'teaRecipe']0: "basil_iced_tea"1: "chai_cider"2: "hot_chocolate"3: "pumpkin_latte"4: "macha_lemonade"5: "habiscus_tea"6: "lavendar_latte"7: "teaRecipe"length: 8[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
10-tea-recipes.js:29 Image Node: undefined
10-tea-recipes.js:31 Recipe Image Data: null
10-tea-recipes.js:26 Recipe Image: ../images/macha_lemonade.webp


Try using Img instead of GatsbyImage
It should look like this:
              <Img src={recipeImage} alt={recipe.title} className="w-full h-64 object-cover mb-4" />

